# Flipping a polygon that contains many polygons to create an upside down mirror of everything

Tags: java, math, geometry, polygons

I have created a polygon with 6 vertices. Lets call this one, outside polygon. Inside the outside polygon I created smaller polygons. I want to flip all of it vertically one point at the time.

I know the vertices of the outside polygon and I have an `ArrayList<Polygon>` for the inner polygons. I was able to flip the outside polygon. but how do I flipped the inner polygons keeping their relative positions in the new one? I know the center of the outside polygon and the flipped version.

correction: I needed to flip horizontal. 
I flipped the outer polygon (triangle shape), and I was able to move the inner polygons. but the distance is incorrect. this is a picture of what  I have done,
(https://docs.google.com/drawings/d/1cPYJqxTWVu5gSHFQyHxHWSTysNzxJvNuJIwsgCQInfc/edit) https://docs.google.com/drawings/d/1cPYJqxTWVu5gSHFQyHxHWSTysNzxJvNuJIwsgCQInfc/edit

I tried this:

```
 for (Polygon p : polygonList) {

                    Polygon tempP = new Polygon(p.xpoints, p.ypoints, p.npoints);

                    firstPointinPolygon = new Point(p.xpoints[0], p.ypoints[0]);
                    // find frist point in the polygon 

                    float adjacent = (float) firstPointinPolygon.getX() - 400;
                    float opposite = (float) firstPointinPolygon.getY() - 400;

                    float hypotenuse = (float) Math.sqrt(opposite * opposite + adjacent * adjacent);

                    float cosine = adjacent / hypotenuse;
                    float sine = opposite / hypotenuse;

                    float endX = 400 * cosine;
                    float endY = 400 * sine;

                    float endXDelta =400-endX;
                    float endYDelta=400-endY;

                    Polygon pM = move(tempP, endX, endY);


                    polygonListMirror.add(pM);

                    tempP = new Polygon();
                }

public Polygon move(Polygon p, double xMove, double yMove) {

 // Change the values of the points for the Polygon
    for (int i = 0; i < p.xpoints.length; i++) {

        p.xpoints[i] += xMove;
        p.ypoints[i] += yMove;

    }
    return p;
}
```

But did not get the result, I expected.   What am I doing wrong? The end result should be like the picture in this link:
(https://docs.google.com/drawings/d/1vYdWkCelWW1_NUypNhtmckBYfEMzCf6bMVtoB-AyPkw/edit) https://docs.google.com/drawings/d/1vYdWkCelWW1_NUypNhtmckBYfEMzCf6bMVtoB-AyPkw/edit

Comment: When you say "flip", do you mean a reflection around a horizontal axis, or a rotation of 180 degrees?

Answer (score 0):

I think something like this will do it:

```
Polygon outerPolygon, oldOuterPolygon;
ArrayList<Polygon> innerPolygons;
// set up objects
for (Polygon polygon: innerPolygons)
{
  for (int i = 0; i < polygon.ypoints.length; i++)
  {
    polygon.ypoints[i] = center(outerPolygon) - polygon.ypoints[i] + center(oldOuterPolygon);
  }
}
```

If you just to flip it vertically where it stands, such that the y-coordinate of top-most and bottom-most points just switch around, center for both should be the same (thus you can just say 2*center).

I'm pretty sure you can replace center(outerPolygon) and center(oldOuterPolygon) with any point from the applicable Polygon, as long as both use the same point.